# PHP shell_exec times out page

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell, ssh

I have a shell script on server that I am calling from a php page, which is part of an api to stream data from a DB.

The shell script sets up port binding between my sever and an 3rd part sever that sits behind a firewall where the database lives.  I have set up password less ssh between our two severs and when I run the script in terminal in executes without a problem and I can refresh my php page and data is returned from their database.

```
lsof -n -i:3311 | grep LISTEN | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq | xargs -r kill -9
ssh -fNg -L 3311:127.0.0.1:3306 user@ipaddress
```

The php code is attempting to restart the connection when the servers lose/drop the binding and I can no longer perform a mysql query

```
shell_exec("sh start_sever.sh");
```

However the script takes for ever to run and the page times out. It does however execute the shell script and if I comment out the shell_exec line then data is returned.

Can you think of

1) Why the binding between the two servers periodically is lost?
2) Why does the shell_exec command kill the page - simple command like ls -a runs fine.
3) Would a solution like running a cronjob to execute the shell script every x minutes be a better idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up the ssh authentication for the account that runs the webserver and the target server or your *own* account on the webserver and the target server?

When scripts time out in situations like this it can be because they're waiting for STDIN, which will be the case if you've not set up key authentication for the account running the webserver and the target server. It will be expecting a password to be entered and will wait until either that happens or php times out the shell_exec.

Comment: Yes I have set up password less ssh key authentication between the www-data user on our sever (running under apache) and also the other servers.  In terminal I can login into our sever as the www-data user and ssh into both severs without the use of a password.

Comment: OK, you can try closing stdin then and see if it is waiting for input or if it's a different problem: `sh start_server.sh < /dev/null`

Comment: Added the < /dev/null, but the page still freezes it its response.  Stop the process of the page and switch to terminal logged in as www-data and run lsof -i :3311 and the binding show up. Comment out the shell_exec command, save and refresh the php and the data loads.  So the script is running successfully and not waiting for a password, but is not moving pass that line and executing the rest of the code.

Comment: switched it to sh start_server.sh > /dev/null and it seems to be working. thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.